# PostgreSQL 9.3: IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to check whether the table exists or not in the database.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE Table_name = 'test') THEN

    RAISE INFO 'Not exists';

else

    RAISE INFO 'Exists';

end if;
```

Getting an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE Table_name = 'test') THEN

    RAISE INFO 'Not exists';

else

    RAISE INFO 'Exists';

end if;
end;
$do$
```

You should surround your postgresql statements with block

Comment: why this works?

Answer (score 0):

`IF NOT EXISTS` is not valid in that context within (what appears like) *plpgsql*.

It can be used in contexts like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo`.

In a *plpgsql* context, you should use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` combined with `ROW_COUNT`.

The doc gives the following code snippet for that:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

If `integer_var` (which you will need to have previously declared) is 0, you know that the table doesn't exist.

See the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html) for more details.